# Attempted import error: 'cloneElement' is not exported from 'react' using deck.gl with react + next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, deck.gl

I have a project without errors using React + Typescript + Nextjs, however when I install and try to use I get the following error:

> Attempted import error: 'cloneElement' is not exported from 'react'.
>
> Could not find files for /index in .next/build-manifest.json
>
> ModuleDependencyError: "export 'cloneElement' was not found in 'react'

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "normma",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.8.0",
    "@brazilian-utils/is-valid-cpf": "^1.0.0-alpha.3",
    "@deck.gl/core": "^8.0.15",
    "@deck.gl/layers": "^8.0.15",
    "@deck.gl/react": "^8.0.15",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^11.0.2",
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.11.2",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@types/canvas-confetti": "^0.1.0",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/firebase": "^3.2.1",
    "@types/react-geosuggest": "^2.7.10",
    "@types/react-map-gl": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/react-select": "^3.0.10",
    "@types/react-stripe-elements": "^6.0.3",
    "amplitude-js": "^5.8.0",
    "canvas-confetti": "^1.0.3",
    "charming": "^3.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^6.0.3",
    "deck.gl": "^8.0.15",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.0.0",
    "firebase": "^7.6.2",
    "imagemin-mozjpeg": "^8.0.0",
    "imagemin-optipng": "^7.1.0",
    "imagemin-svgo": "^7.0.0",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jimp": "^0.9.3",
    "next": "^9.2.1",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.0",
    "next-offline": "^5.0.0-beta.9",
    "next-optimized-images": "^2.5.4",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^3.0.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-day-picker": "^7.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-geosuggest": "^2.12.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^4.4.8",
    "react-map-gl": "^5.2.3",
    "react-modal": "^3.11.1",
    "react-modal-hook": "^2.0.0",
    "react-responsive": "8.0.1",
    "react-select": "^3.0.8",
    "react-spring": "^9.0.0-beta.34",
    "react-text-mask": "^5.4.3",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "responsive-loader": "^1.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.1.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.0",
    "text-mask-addons": "^3.8.0",
    "ts-jest": "^24.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4",
    "uifx": "^2.0.7",
    "webp-loader": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.8.0",
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^9.1.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/amplitude-js": "^4.4.5",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.4",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.25",
    "@types/node": "^13.1.6",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.4",
    "@types/react-modal": "^3.10.3",
    "@types/react-responsive": "^8.0.2",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.9.1",
    "@types/react-text-mask": "^5.4.6",
    "@types/react-transition-group": "^4.2.3",
    "@types/styled-components": "^4.4.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.16.0",
    "@zeit/next-source-maps": "0.0.4-canary.1",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-plugin-object-to-json-parse": "^0.0.9",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.3",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.9.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.17.0",
    "ignore-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.2.0",
    "jest-styled-components": "^7.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.12.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_PATH=. next",
    "build": "NODE_PATH=. next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint './**/**.{ts,tsx,js}'",
    "deploy": "now",
    "analyze": "cross-env ANALYZE=true npm run build",
    "analyze:server": "cross-env BUNDLE_ANALYZE=server npm run build",
    "analyze:browser": "cross-env BUNDLE_ANALYZE=browser npm run build"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

```js
import React from 'react';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore
// @ts-ignore
import DeckGL from '@deck.gl/react';
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore
//  @ts-ignore
import { LineLayer } from '@deck.gl/layers';

// Viewport settings
const viewState = {
  longitude: -122.41669,
  latitude: 37.7853,
  zoom: 13,
  pitch: 0,
  bearing: 0,
};

// Data to be used by t he LineLayer
const data = [{ sourcePosition: [-122.41669, 37.7853], targetPosition: [-122.41669, 37.781] }];

// return (
//   <DeckGL viewState={viewState} layers={layers} />
// );

const Home = () => {
  const layers = [
    new LineLayer({ id: 'line-layer', data }),
  ];

  return <DeckGL viewState={viewState} layers={layers} />;
};
export default Home;
```